# ESXi 4.x VMware Clone and Snapshot

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I would like to clone a vm and revert the clone back to the snapshop, I have cloned the VM but when I go to snapshot manager there are no previous snapshots listed.

Is it possible to revert back this clone or is it only possible with the original vm.

Answer (score 1):

The snapshot only exists on the original VM. It wouldn't make sense for the cloned virtual machine to have the snapshot history of the original VM.

Comment: So can I create a VM from the clone, as described in this article. http://malaysiavm.com/blog/make-a-clone-from-a-snapshot/

Comment: I know this refers to workstation but is this feature  available in vsphere and i just havent discovered it.. http://malaysiavm.com/blog/make-a-clone-from-a-snapshot/